# Finding a bijection of the set of $n-$bitstrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $w$ be a bitstring of length $n$ i.e. it has $n$ bits of $0$ or $1$. Let $S$ be the set of all possible bitstrings of length $n$. Let $H(w)$ be the Hamming weight of $w$ i.e. $H(w)$ is the number of $1'$s in the string. The space I am looking at is such that strings with same Hamming weight are close to each other. So starting from a $w$, and after applying $f$ twice, I would want to be in $w'$ s.t. $H(w')\neq H(w)$.

> So starting from a fixed $w$, I am looking for a formula for a bijection $f:S\to S$ s.t.:
> $$H(f(f(w))\neq H(w)$$

For example, if $f$ is a bijection such that it flips the bits i.e. $1$ to $0$ and vice-versa then the above condition is not true. So the bijection, qualitatively, has to look like:

$f$ maps $\{w: H(w)=1\}$ to $\{w:H(w)=2\}$ and map $\{w:H(w)=2\}$ to $\{w:H(w)=3\}$ and so on or something else of that kind. But obviously

$$|\{w: H(w)=i\}|\neq |\{w: H(w)=j\}|\text{ for i }\neq j$$

and hence it is hard to find such a bijection. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have $f$ just work on the first two bits with

$f(00)=01, f(01)=10, f(10)=11, f(11)=00$.

$f(f(w))$ has weight $1$ different from $w$ in all cases.